# Toggle ArcGIS Online WebMap Layers using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am taking an intro course on webmapping and am having some trouble figuring out how to set up a layer list and toggle layers on/off.

I have already preconfigured 2 layers in a WebMap using ArcGIS Online. One is FeatureLayer and the other is a MapImageLayer. My first issue is that my FeatureLayer is not showing up in my legend. The second is that I cannot get the layer list to show up. I would like the ability to turn my layers on/off as needed.

This is what I am trying to accomplish: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-layerlist

I've tried copying the list layers function into my code but am struggling to wrap my head around what I need to to get it to work correctly. Also, not sure why my Legend is only showing 1 of my 2 layers.

```
  <script>
require([
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/widgets/Legend",
    "esri/WebMap",
    "esri/widgets/Locate",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/widgets/ScaleBar",
    "esri/widgets/LayerList",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
  ],
  function(
    MapView, Legend, WebMap, Locate, Search, ScaleBar, FeatureLayer, LayerList
  ) {

    var webmap = new WebMap({
      portalItem: { // autocasts as new PortalItem()
        id: "2ce3aa115bb044a9af0e73929268975e"
      }
    });

    var view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: webmap
    });

    var locateBtn = new Locate({
    view: view
    });

    // Add the locate widget to the top left corner of the view
    view.ui.add(locateBtn, {
    position: "top-left"
    });

    view.when(function() {
      // get the first layer in the collection of operational layers in the WebMap
      // when the resources in the MapView have loaded.
      var featureLayer = webmap.layers.getItemAt(0);

      var legend = new Legend({
        view: view,
        layerInfos: [{
          layer: featureLayer,
          title: "Legend"
        }]
      });

      // Add widget to the bottom right corner of the view
      view.ui.add(legend, "bottom-left");
    });

    var searchWidget = new Search({
    view: view
    });

      // Add the search widget to the top right corner of the view
    view.ui.add(searchWidget, {
    position: "top-right"
    });

    var scaleBar = new ScaleBar({
  view: view
});
  // Add widget to the bottom left corner of the view
view.ui.add(scaleBar, {
  position: "bottom-right"
  });

view.when(function() {
    var layerList = new LayerList({
      view: view
    });

    // Add widget to the top right corner of the view
    view.ui.add(layerList, "top-right");
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your modules are mapped incorrectly. You have `LayerList` going to `FeatureLayer` and `FeatureLayer` going to `LayerList`. Reverse them in this line so that they match the order of your module paths.

`function(
    MapView, Legend, WebMap, Locate, Search, ScaleBar, FeatureLayer, LayerList
  ) {`

should be

`function(
    MapView, Legend, WebMap, Locate, Search, ScaleBar, LayerList, FeatureLayer
  ) {`

*Edit: Actually, looking at your code more you don't even need the `FeatureLayer` module, as you are not instantiating a new one. You also had a minor syntax error, missing one final `});` to close out your `require` function. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itrew/rcL9ybqk/10/) of your code.

As for why only one layer is showing up in your legend, it's because you explicitly tell it to when you use the `layerInfos` option. Removing that shows all visible layers in your legend.